# MultibyteToWideChar Byte Boundary

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am attempting to use `MultibyteToWideChar` to convert some text in ANY encoding supported by that function, to another encoding such as `UTF-8`.

The issue is that `MultibyteToWideChar` when used along a character boundary will just report the error, but will give NO indication at which character it failed at.
Take this:

```
tes字hello
```

and say it's `UTF-8`. I want to convert it into `UTF-16`.

Now for my situation, I read say 4 bytes. I Then, I call `MultibyteToWideChar` on those 4 bytes.
Well, the asian character is split into 2 boundaries.

Now `MultibyteToWideChar` will fail, and will NOT tell me WHICH BYTE it failed, so I can readjust.

I read 4 bytes, or bufferSize bytes, because I have streaming data.

I have used [iconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) for encoding conversion, but it's MUCH too slow.

I have also used [ICU](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu), and it's fast, but with it completely trimmed it is STILL 6.5MB in size which is too big.

Is there another solution that is also fast but small and supports a wide range of encodings?

I have also tried the CharNextExA functions and such but they don't work with other encodings.

The return value of the function only returns characters, and so I do not know how many bytes have been converted. Multibyte characters can vary in length.
I need the number of bytes converted because then I can copy over those bytes into the next buffer for reuse.

What I'm trying to do is read in a very large file in chunks, and convert that files encoding, which varies, into UTF-8

**NOTE**:

I'm curious, how does ICU4C work? Basically, I copy the source files over, but out of box it only supports encoding like UTF-8, but not Big5. To add Big5, I have to create a 5MB .data file which I then send to ICU4C, and then Big5 is availiable. The thing is, I don't think the .data  file is code. Because when compiled for x64, it works perfectly fine for x86. Is there a way to avoid that 5MB?

Comment: "Now for my situation, I read say 4 bytes." -- Why? The function is intended to operate on string buffers, [as far as I can see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar), and operate on that in one go. Why do you "read 4 bytes", instead of passing the whole string to the function as input?

Comment: As for ICU, it's large, but it's (to my knowledge) the only *complete* Unicode implementation available. There is more than just conversion; there is collation, normalization, word boundary detection etc., stuff that other implementations just don't cover. And all those lookup tables take up a lot of space, even optimized / compressed as they are. Can't be helped, really, if you want to "do it right".

Comment: You're right, but I stripped all that other stuff up with a filters.json file. The conversion package alone is 5MB

Comment: @DevSolar I read 4 bytes or x bytes at a time because I'm parsing a large file.

Comment: @personmanperson Which [code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) you passed in `MultiByteToWideChar()`?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I should be able to pass in any code page to `MultibyteToWideChar`

Comment: @personmanperson Got it. Can you show the exact code reproduces the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a one function solution.

Without using a 3rd-party library you might be stuck with something like this:

- Read a byte into a buffer.
- If `IsDBCSLeadByteEx` is true, append the next byte to the buffer.
- Call `MultiByteToWideChar`. If this fails the trailing byte (if any) was incorrect.

Note that `IsDBCSLeadByteEx` does not support Unicode so when the code page is UTF-8 you need to do your own length handling until your buffer contains one complete code point.

Comment: Windows 10 CU added the ICU library, it might also be able to help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/international-components-for-unicode--icu-

Answer (score -1):

You could use  the return value from MultiByteToWideChar as an input to WideCharToMultiByte and then the length would tell you the number of MB characters that were converted. Most of the time if I need this level of detail I simply suck it up and use ICU and ignore the resulting size.

Comment: The issue is, even if I know the number of MB characters, I do not know how many **bytes** have been converted. Multibyte characters can vary in length.

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar says it returns a character count but I suspect that actually means how many wchar_t were written not UTF-16 characters. WideCharToMultiByte returns the number of bytes not characters. To get a MB character count you would need to use _mbslen (or _mbslen_l) on the re-converted string.

Comment: The thing is, when I call MultibyteToWideChar, and there is a character at the end that has been split, I need how many bytes MultibyteToWideChar does, so that I can copy over the leftovers into the next buffer.